# JQuery DataTable DISABLE "select row" on click

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a simple question using DataTable. How can I disable (or make false) the "(onclick)select row" option?

```
   var oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable({"bPaginate": false}).makeEditable({
      sUpdateURL: "UpdateData.php",
      sRowSelect": false
   });
```

I use this **.makeEditable** to load my table using defaults values, BUT this values include the select row.

I tried **"sRowSelect": false**  without success :(

I will appreciate any help

Comment: If you don't use sRowSelect, how would you edit your table?

Comment: I just tried sRwowSelect to see if the "selectable" option disappear. I can still edit my table by cells individually

Comment: so you want your table to be editale or not?

Comment: yes friend, I want my table to be editable ONLY by cells, not selecting the row. This seems to be the cleanest way http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/editable.html but it could be more clean if you use .makeEditable without row select option

Comment: see Show Detail of sRowSelect http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/initialisation,... [TableTools provides everything that is needed to allow the end user to select rows in a table (by clicking on them). This is disabled by default, but can be readily enabled by setting this property to either "single" (to allow only one row in the table to be selected at a time), or "multi" (to allow any number of rows to be selected).]

Comment: what about you dont't call sRowSelect in your function?

Comment: also check here for css fix, http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5842/how-to-select-individual-cell-instead-of-the-whole-role/p1

Comment: thanks for taking your time in my question.
Yes, I had that page on my favorite (http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/initialisation) and I read that info (sRowSelect is disabled by deflaut) and still not working, the table keep making the select row clicking. I just tried ONCE that sRowSelect-false to test :P

Comment: I can do that through css years ago, but is not the propper way. Is sad, there is not a direct command to disable it :(

Comment: There is a type error in your script [sRowSelect": false], should be [sRowSelect: ""]...
have you remove [sRowSelect: false] and test?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sSelectedRowClass` option and set it to class other than `row_selected`.

For example:

```
var oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable({
   "bPaginate": false
}).makeEditable({
   sUpdateURL: "UpdateData.php",
   sSelectedRowClass: "row-selected-custom"
});
```

That way selected rows will not be highlighted.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as the select is still happening and triggering events.